# How is flush: true different from manually flushing the currentSession?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a GORM object that I'm working with in an integration test. It has a `beforeUpdate` hook that keeps a history of the previous password hashes. The code looks something like this:

```
class Credentials {
    List passwordHistory = []
    String username
    String password

    static hasMany = [passwordHistory : String]

    def beforeUpdate() {
        // of course I'm not really storing plain-text passwords, but
        // this is just for illustration.
        if (isDirty('password')) { passwordHistory << password }
    }
}
```

In the integration test, I'm wondering why:

```
appUser.credentials.password = newPassword
appUser.save(flush: true)
sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
AppUser.withNewSession {
    appUser = AppUser.get(appUser.id)
    appUser.credentials.empty // eagerly fetch the list while session is open
}
assert !appUser.credentials.passwordHistory.empty() // contains the previous password
```

works, but

```
appUser.credentials.password = newPassword
appUser.save()
sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
AppUser.withNewSession {
    appUser = AppUser.get(appUser.id)
    appUser.credentials.empty // eagerly fetch the list while session is open
}
assert !appUser.credentials.passwordHistory.empty() // is empty
```

does not. The difference is the `flush: true` in the `appUser.save()` call. I thought the call to `save()` attached the object to the current session, but flushing the current session does not add the password to the `passwordHistory` list. What's really going on here?

Comment: Just a thought, what happens if you change the `get()` to `findById()`?

Comment: Quick thought: the default initializer (`... = []`) for `passwordHistory` might be confusing things.  Try removing this.  You will, of course, need to also change the way you append to the list.

Comment: One more thought: does the behavior change if you use `addToPasswordHistory(...)` rather than a direct append (though I'm not immediately sure if `addTo` is supported for primitive collections...)

Comment: @Andrew `addToPasswordHistory(...)` seemed to initialize this list for me when I didn't have it initialized to `[]`, but I noticed the same behavior with the session flushing. In other words, I tried both scenarios you mentioned and it didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: @SérgioMichels I'll check this evening. Do you know why it would make a difference?

Comment: @Joe I was thinking about the get cache, but Andrew's comments seem more accurate in your issue.

Comment: Hibernate session.flush() depends on the FlushMode and Transaction Commit. May be thats playing a role here. Grails sets the default Flush Mode to AUTO. try changing that to MANUAL and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting the Grails code correctly, you're actually dealing with two different sessions.  From the documentation:

> Integration tests run inside a database transaction by default, which
>   is rolled back at the end of the each test. This means that data saved
>   during a test is not persisted to the database.

If you dig through the Grails GORM method logic, you'll see that when you're within a transaction, GORM grabs its session from a `ThreadLocal` resources map that's maintained by the `TransactionSynchronizationManager` class.  If it doesn't find one, it opens a new session and binds it to the map - important distinction, it explicitly opens a new session. It doesn't just call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

At the end of the `save()` GORM logic, if you pass in `flush:true` it will flush the session associated with the transaction - the one it got from the resources map in `TransactionSynchronizationManager`.

On the other hand when you call `flush()` you're calling it on the session that you get from `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` which I believe is a session bound to your thread from the `CurrentSessionContext` used by the Hibernate `SessionFactory`.  The actual implementation of `CurrentSessionContext` is beside the point because (unless there's a Grails-specific implementation that I'm missing) it wouldn't return the same session that's held by the `TransactionSynchronizationManager`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you flush the session, so the object become "dirty".
When you open a new session with newSession closure, you can modify an object, but if you want to make the modification "dirty" you must do an explicit call to the save() method in the new session open. 
If you do that, after closure closed, you can see the modification you made at the object in the closure.

In the second case before the withNewSession the object isn't dirty, so non explicit call is nedeed for modifying the object, and this is the reason why you see the list empty in the second case.